# « Il est irrespectueux des choix des autres » ou « Il est irrespectueux envers les choix des autres »

Tags: choix-de-mot, formulation-idiomatique, formulation, reformulation

Il est irrespectueux des choix d’autrui.

Il est irrespectueux envers les choix d’autrui.

Comment: *C'qu'y veulent les autres, y s'en balek.* ;-)

Comment:  hé là là, une chance que je ne m’exprime pas de cette manière!

Comment: Si vous utilisez un verbe, les jeux sont faits plus facilement: Il ne respecte pas les choix des autres.

Comment: @Lambie Cette phrase m’a aussi traversé l’esprit avant d’opter pour une tournure positive. Merci tout de même pour votre commentaire, d’autres pourront le trouver pertinent.

Comment: Je pense que vous voulez dire une phrase déclarative.

Comment: Peut-être bien, je ne connais pas le jargon des linguistes ni des grammairiens.

Comment: Ce n'est pas du "jargon". C'est un vocabulaire de base pour apprendre une langue. https://www.pass-education.fr/types-de-phrases-declaratives-interrogative-imperative-exclamative-cm2-exercices-corriges-grammaire-francais-cycle-3/ Dans votre langue maternelle, ne dit-on pas une phrase déclarative>

Comment: Sauf que le vocabulaire de base peut varier d’une nationalité à l’autre, il faut en tenir compte.

Comment: On dit plutôt une phrase « affirmative ».

Comment: Voire formulation positive, sans utiliser la négation. Peut-être que vous avez mal interprété mon propos.

Comment: http://www.visezjuste.uottawa.ca/pages/redaction/faites_des_phrases_affirmatives.html

Comment: Et pourquoi vouloir fermer cette question ? En quoi elle est pire que les autres ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La préposition « envers » a cela de particulier qu'elle ne s'utilise avant un nom *essentiellement* que si c'est celui d'une personne, cette personne pouvant être soit une personne physique soit une personne morale. Cette assertion s'appuie sur l'entrée « [envers¹](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/envers) » du TLFi. Cependant, il existe des cas de nom abstraits qui peuvent convenir ; la notion précise desquels il peut s'agir ne s'acquiert qu'après beaucoup de lecture, mais un bon dictionnaire est d'une aide très appréciable pour décider.

Dans la partie « A » la parenthèse « (quelqu'un) » montre que le complément de la préposition doit être une personne physique ; comme il est nécessaire que « envers » fasse partie d'une locution comprenant « contre » (**A.** − [Uniquement ds les loc. fig., coordonné à *contre*] En face de, vis-à-vis de (quelqu'un)), la section « A » n'apporte rien en fait de précision sur l'usage.

Dans « B », qui est la section des usages habituels (**B.** − *Usuel*. À l'égard de.), on doit exclure « **1.** » à cause de la précision « Le comp. prép. désigne une pers., une collectivité ». Il reste donc le « 2 » et le « 3 », et « 3 » ne convient pas puisque il faut que le complément soit un nom concret, ce que « choix » n'est pas. Il reste dans le « 2 » l'unique possibilité du « **b)** », comme on peut voir facilement, puisque « irréspectueux » est un adjectif.  Il n'y a donc rien qui empêche l'usage de « envers ». Cependant, l'usage qu'il est fait de cette préposition dans des constructions dont le complément est une personne est beaucoup plus important, et ce dernier usage spécialisé aux cas où c'est un adjectif qui précède, est encore plus rare que l'usage après un nom lorsque le complément est un nom abstrait ; cela semble une raison pour le peu de légitimité que semble avoir cet usage de « envers », mais il est idiomatique dans la forme.

*On ne trouve rien pour* « adj. - envers - le choix ».

*On trouve*

- irrespectueux envers la mémoire, irrespectueux envers ses qualités,  irrespectueux envers la Patrie, irrespectueux envers les lois, irrespectueux envers l'Etat, irrespectueux envers la Bible, irrespectueux envers le Passé , irrespectueux envers l'image de Notre-Dame, irrespectueux envers nous et envers la montagne et la déesse Chomolungma,
- coupable envers la patrie, nécessaire envers la patrie, loyal envers la patrie
- dogmatiques envers la religion, juste envers la religion,
- soumis envers l'état,
- dédaigneux envers mon travail, dédaigneux envers les autres langues, dédaigneux envers la mort, dur et dédaigneux envers une affection, dédaigneux envers la religion, dédaigneux envers le passé, complètement dédaigneux envers le Rapport de la Commission d'enquête, dédaigneux envers des compliments, dédaigneux envers les magnificences infinies de notre radieuse Reine, dédaigneux envers les instruments spéciaux , dédaigneux, envers ce que son ami écrivait,
- avide envers ce bas monde,
- triste envers leur situation,

En conclusion, bien que « envers » ne donne pas la même impression de naturel que « des », c'est  une préposition correcte que l'on pourrait utiliser tout aussi bien que cette dernière.